# It's?? A Rebus!

Tags: rebus

What is the image below trying to say?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think it says

> It's not rocket science

from

> Its not-symbol rock it's eye hints (hints from hint from OP :))

Comment: Oof, 8 seconds.

Comment: @Avi i'm usually on the other side of an 8 second snipe! my apologies!

Comment: Intended to be rot13("uvagf") at the end but that's correct, nice!